# What does "2>&1" here mean?

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In the bash shell, what is “ 2>&1 ”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21)

```
#echo "[+] Creating $count files" 
_remount 
create=$((time ./dirtest $testdir $count $size) 2>&1)
```

Comment: From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21), it's a redirect of stderr to stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the standard error descriptor `stderr` (2) is to be redirected to the standard output descriptor `stdout` (1). Notice that the `&` ensures that the `1` is interpreted as a file descriptor and not a filename.

Answer (score 2):

It redirects standard error to the standard output. This way the result written to stderr will be stored in the variable.